# What's wrong with my code to delete duplicate-value nodes from a sorted linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Problem statement:
Delete duplicate-value nodes from a sorted linked list

Input Format:

You have to complete the Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node* head) method which takes one argument - the head of the sorted linked list. You should NOT read any input from stdin/console.

Output Format:

Delete as few nodes as possible to ensure that no two nodes have the same data. Adjust the next pointers to ensure that the remaining nodes form a single sorted linked list. Then return the head of the sorted updated linked list.

My Code:

```
Node RemoveDuplicates(Node head) {   
    Node n  = head;
    while(n.next!=null){
        Node test = n.next;
        while(n.data==test.data){
            if(test.next!=null){
                n.next = test.next;
                test = n.next;
            }
            else{
                n.next = null;
            }
        }
        if((n.next!=null)){
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

When tested, it runs perfectly except when the last node's value is equal to previous node's value. I couldn't find the mistake in my code.

Test results:

[image]

The first int is the number of test cases and second int is the number of nodes in the list.

Problem taken [from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/delete-duplicate-value-nodes-from-a-sorted-linked-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just not finishing the loop.

Lets debug what happens when in this case,

```
n.data = 15;
n.next = test;
test.data = 15;
test.next == null;
```

You inner while loop will return true, and you will enter the else condition.

There you are setting `n.next = null` and continuing with the loop. **But the loops condition remains the same... So it will go into an infinite loop**.

**Fix:**
Just break out of the loop after setting `n.next = null`.

```
else{
    n.next = null;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. I may have overlooked the else  condition. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

change your inner while loop to

```
    while(n.next!=null && n.data==test.data){
       .....
    }
```

when your last two nodes are equal, you are making `n.next=null;` but you not checking whether next is null or not, just checking `n.data` && `test.data`, which is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The code is also overly complicated. Try this (couldn't test right now):

```
Node RemoveDuplicates(Node head) {   
    if (head == null) return null;
    Node prev  = head;
    Node curr = head.next;
    while(curr != null){
        if (prev.data == curr.data)
            prev.next = curr.next;
         else
             prev = prev.next;
         curr = curr.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```